# Prove the following equation

Tags: matrices

Show that

$e^{J\omega t} = I_{2\times 2}\cos{\omega t} + J\sin{\omega t}$

Where $I_{2\times 2}$ is a $2\times 2$ identity matrix and $J$ is equal to

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & -1  \\
        1 & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}\right)$$

I am currently lost on how to prove this equation. I suspect that you have to use Euler's identity to prove it. However, when I try to use Euler's identity there is supposed to be a complex exponent so I am having trouble fitting the equation to it. Am I taking the wrong approach?

Comment: use the serie representation of exponential and notice that $J^n$ has a period to split the sum

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$
J^2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}-1&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right)=-I_{2\times2},
$$
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
e^{\omega tJ}&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\omega tJ)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\omega t)^k}{k!}J^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\omega t)^{2k}}{(2k)!}J^{2k}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\omega t)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}J^{2k+1}\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\omega t)^{2k}}{(2k)!}(-I)^k+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\omega t)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}(-I)^kJ\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(\omega t)^{2k}}{(2k)!}I+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(\omega t)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}J\\
&=&\cos(\omega t)I+\sin(\omega t)J
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Wow I did not think to use the series expansion formula instead. But how does the initial series expansion turn into a summation of when the exponent is 2k and 2k+1..? Shouldn't it be 2k-1 instead?

Comment: It is $2k-1$ if you go from $k=1$ to $\infty$, but it is $2k+1$ if you go from $k=1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: I'm sorry I think there is a typo in your last comment. Did you mean 2k-1 for k=0 and 2k+1 for k=1 to infinity? Also, is there a simple explanation as to why this happens?

Comment: NO! there is no typo. Try to list all the numbers of the form $2k-1$ for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$, and all those of the form $2k+1$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$